# Adding custom body class to the custom archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I have created two custom archive pages: `archive-one.php` and `archive-two.php`. Archive pages are placed inside main catalog of my theme. Now what I trying to do is to add a custom body class to each of them like "archive-one" and "archive-two".

I was trying to do this with following code but with no luck:

```
function archive_class_1( $classes ) {
    if ( is_page_template( 'archive-one.php' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'archive-one';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'archive_class_1' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Confirming this is added to you theme `functions.php`?  Next you can use the same function for both custom archive files (see below examples). Are your custom template files at the root of your theme or a sub folder?  if in a sub folder you need to add that path to you check like the examples below.  Also confirming that your theme is using the `<?php body_class(); ?>` function on your themes opening `<body>` tag (something like `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`)?

**Custom files at the root of theme**

```
function my_archive_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_page_template( 'archive-one.php' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'archive-one';
    }

    if ( is_page_template( 'archive-two.php' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'archive-two';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_archive_class' );
```

**Custom files in sub folder "templates" theme**

```
function my_archive_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_page_template( 'templates/archive-one.php' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'archive-one';
    }

    if ( is_page_template( 'archive-two.php' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'templates/archive-two';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_archive_class' );
```

Comment: Yes it is inside template root. Yes I use ```<body <?php body_class(); ?>>```. I've added your code but ca't see any results. Still body classes are only "blog logged-in hfeed no-sidebar". I am building my template on underscores.me theme starter.

Comment: I am not sure is this code will work also inside archive pages. It works only in page templates files imho. :/

Comment: Oh duh I missed the "Archive" specific part.... Are these custom archives for custom post types?

Comment: No, I use this templates to display pages from specific category.

Comment: Are you sure your custom archive pages are being used?  Can you add some detail about how they get pull in in place of the standard `archive.php`?

Comment: Following up.  I just tested this locally with a test page using a custom archive template I created, used same names as your post and the filter works as expected.  Curious to learn more about how you are loading these custom templates?

Comment: Hmm, I just simply named files with adding filename after "archive" archive-myname.php nothing else. Same as with page id's like page-24.php etc. - Is there other way to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240935/discussion-between-mikerojas-and-mike).

Answer (score 0):

add below code it will work properly.

```
function my_archive_class( $classes ) {
    if ( basename( get_page_template()) == 'archive-one.php') {
        $classes[] = 'archive-one';
    }

    if ( basename( get_page_template()) == 'archive-two.php') {
        $classes[] = 'archive-two';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_archive_class' );
```